# Texture painting paints another place due to UV overlapping. How could I fix it?

Tags: uv, texture-painting, topology

[image: UV and topology of the anvil]

No subsurf modifier applied mesh. UV islands stick together.

[image: Bleeding?]
Like above image, When texture painting, painting near seams paints wrong place.
Reducing bleed px won't solve the problem.
[image: seam fixed]
I cleared some seams to fix the problem but it still happens another place.

Do I have to move the uv island manually to avoid overlapping problem or is there a better way to fix it?

Comment: If the UVs are overlapping you have no other choice but moving the islands, yes